# Did Adobe abandon AIR for mobile app development?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

Did Adobe abandon AIR for mobile app development as it did with flex and flash player?

Comment: Voted to close - that's a question you'd have to ask Adobe.

Comment: @sirask: 1. Flex was not abandoned, but flex was donated to Apache. 2. AIR and Flash player are still under Adobe's governance and they were not "abandoned".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently attended a [conference on the future of web and mobile development](http://www.futureinsightslive.com) and Adobe was there pushing its [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) platform pretty heavily.

Comment: I just attended a conference where Adobe was pushing the HTML work they were doing, such as CSS Regions and Shadow.  I didn't take that to mean that Adobe was abandoning PhoneGap.  Adobe is a big company with lots of moving parts.  Promotion of one thing does not necessarily mean abandonment of another.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, True. I don't know exactly what Adobe's big plans are going forward. I'm just going by what the reps were telling me when I was asking them about Adobe's mobile phone development plans. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Please read Adobe's [Flash Platform Roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html) for more information.

Adobe is using AIR to build all of the touch tools that integrate with Creative Cloud.  I, personally, consider that a commitment to the platform.